# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when I use shutil.copy() to copy a csv file from one folder to the other

Tags: python, windows-10, permission-denied, shutil

> I am just trying to copy files that have a unique group name after the
>   second _. There is a total of three such groups. I am trying to
>   separate these into 3 different folders. I have been having issues
>   with shutil.copy. Python version 3.

## CODE:

#

```
import os, os.path, shutil

folder_path = 'nodelists'
all_cells = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if 
os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_path, f))]
print("Length of all cells:",len(all_cells))

count=0
for cell in all_cells:
    folder_name = cell.split('_')[2]
    new_path = folder_name+"_nodelists"
    if not os.path.exists(new_path):
        os.mkdir(new_path)

    old_cell_path = os.path.join(folder_path, cell)
    shutil.copy(old_cell_path,new_path)

    count+=1

    if count % 500 == 0:
        print ("Progress:",count, " done")
        print("cell id is", str(cell))
```

###OUTPUT:

```
Length of all cells: 15533
Progress: 500  done
cell id is AAGCGTTCAACTAGAA-1_nodelist_old_.csv
Progress: 1000  done
...
DISPLAYS RESULTS CORRECTLY! I am even able to open and check these files.##
...
Progress: 9500  done
cell id is GGGACCTAGCGACTAG-1_nodelist_postnatal_.csv

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-90d1a4cf5db0> in <module>()
     20     #new_cell_path = os.path.join(new_path, cell)
     21     #shutil.copy(old_cell_path, new_cell_path)
---> 22     shutil.copy(old_cell_path,new_path)
     23 
     24     count+=1

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py in copy(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    239     if os.path.isdir(dst):
    240         dst = os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(src))
--> 241     copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
    242     copymode(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
    243     return dst

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py in copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    120         with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
    121             with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
--> 122                 copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
    123     return dst
    124 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py in copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst, length)
     77     """copy data from file-like object fsrc to file-like object fdst"""
     78     while 1:
---> 79         buf = fsrc.read(length)
     80         if not buf:
     81             break

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

#

> I tried giving Jupyter permission by "Running as administrator". These
>   still didn't seem to go through. I am using Windows 10 and wasn't able
>   to find a security tab for my folders. All these folders are on my BOX
>   sync folder.
>
> Any help is greatly appreciated!
>
> EDIT: After I tried: try/except for PermissionError, I am now getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-909c0ceea90a> in <module>()
     19 
     20     try:
---> 21         shutil.copy(old_cell_path,new_path)
     22 
     23     except PermissionError as error:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py in copy(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    239     if os.path.isdir(dst):
    240         dst = os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(src))
--> 241     copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
    242     copymode(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
    243     return dst

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py in copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    120         with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
    121             with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
--> 122                 copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
    123     return dst
    124 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py in copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst, length)
     77     """copy data from file-like object fsrc to file-like object fdst"""
     78     while 1:
---> 79         buf = fsrc.read(length)
     80         if not buf:
     81             break

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

> Can anyone help debug? Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a Python error, it's OS file permissions; you should have the same problem running the `copy` command at a command prompt, at which point [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) becomes the appropriate place to ask.

Comment: ...that said, it *is* interesting that it's the `read` call, and not one of the `open()`s, where the failure takes place. It's the kind of interesting that someone who knows Windows is more able to answer than someone who knows Python, though.

Comment: I agree. Correct me if I 'm wrong. If it were a Python error, it would have specified which particular csv file it had a problem with, correct?

Comment: Not really -- if you wanted to know that, you should add a `try`/`except` inside the loop that prints the relevant filenames inside the except clause.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like well over 9500 entries completed successfully. I would bet that there is some permissions issue on either one of the folders or one of the files. Open up powershell, navigate to that directory of directories, then run something like:

```
gci | ForEach-Object -Process {Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName}
```

In the provided example, we are looking at the top level of the directory and getting the access control levels for each item in the directory. Adding the `-Recurse` parameter to `gci` would traverse all subdirectories and subitems as well, and may be what you're looking for. Once powershell creates the list, you can filter and explore until the problem file is located.

Alternatively, you could wrap the python copy function in a try/catch and record the errant file/directory name in python, then return the list of errant files and go back after the fact to edit the permissions for those items manually.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this process is to find out exactly which file is causing the issues, correct?

Comment: That would be my understanding. The underlying python libraries, however, will not necessarily explicitly state what the file name would be - a try/except would have to be implemented under the ```for cell in all_cells``` to handle this

Comment: Err 22 is what I am getting now, I am considering raising an exception for that one too! Will that help, you think?

Comment: If the input is invalid, I wonder if you're running in to path length limits and/or escape/invalid characters in the item names?

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful suggestion! But that seems improbable because all names are of the same length and format ie. cellid_nodelist_group.csv. Also, it seems like the number of successful cells is different if I re-execute that cell. I had first gotten 9895 run successfully, then 11569, without errors. Now, it's still running past 13500.

Answer (score 0):

> I was able to copy without any errors after I tried : try/except for both PermissionError and OSError. Even after having these exceptions, it somehow never went through the "except", but successfully copied all the files. I'm not so sure exactly why and how, but this went through successfully.
>   Thanks for all your help!